# Prevent blocking popups that appear with facebook SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, popup

A have trouble with blocking popups which are showed by Facebook JS SDK. After reading documentation, I understand that the call of JS SDK must be after the user's click.
This code works correctly and browser don't block the popup:

```
function Login() {
    FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            DoSmth(response.authResponse.accessToken);
        }
    }, { scope:'user_birthday, publish_stream' });
}
```

But if I will use this code anywhere (for ex. post to wall, get user data), the popup will be displayed in all cases, even if user already logged in in facebook. I consider, it's not fine.

To determine, that user already logged in, I use this code:

```
function CheckOrLogin() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            DoSmth(response.authResponse.accessToken);
        }
        else {
            FB.login(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    DoSmth(response.authResponse.accessToken);
                }
            }, { scope:'user_birthday, publish_stream' });
        }
    }, true);
}
```

In this case popup will not be shown, if user already logged in. But if user hasn't been logged in facebook, this condition (if (response.status ===) returns false. And browser will be **BLOCK** popup, which will be shown by FB.login. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: I'm having the same problem :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to check login status at once when page loaded, and store the result and accessToken in some variable.

```
var userData = {isConnected: false, token: null};
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    userData.isConnected = (response.status === 'connected');
    if (userData.isConnected) {
        userData.token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    }
}, true);
```

When user clicks some button – just check variable's value.

```
function CheckOrLogin() {
    if (userData.isConnected) {
        DoSmth(userData.token);
    } else {
        FB.login(function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                DoSmth(response.authResponse.accessToken);
            }
        }, { scope:'user_birthday, publish_stream' });
    }
}
```